# JOIN column with substring index value

Tags: mysql

i have two different table, one of the table contains substring value separate by comma (,) i would like join the value to another table.

Table campaign

```
id    name           area
1     campaign 1    1,2,3
2     promo         3,4
```

Tabel area

```
id     name
1     Indonesia
2     Singapore
3     Malaysia
4     America
```

expected Result

```
id_campaign   campaign_name   area_name
    1         campaign 1      Indonesia,Singapore,Malaysia
    2         promo           Malaysia,America
```

is there any query to solve this i use mysql 5.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function and string functions to join the values from the two tables.

```
SELECT campaign.id AS id_campaign, campaign.name AS campaign_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(area.name ORDER BY area.id ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS area_name
FROM campaign
JOIN area ON FIND_IN_SET(area.id, campaign.area) > 0
GROUP BY campaign.id
```